# UC Mini's Speed mode not working

Tags: browser

Something went wrong suddenly with my UC Mini browser. Its Speed mode has stopped working on my Android phone. With its Speed mode on, UC Mini works well even over a slow 2G network. But now, turning it on has stopped working.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your data carrier had problems or there's a bug at UC Mini. See if next updates of UC Mini can workaround your problem.